# How to add pagination to data fetched from database in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, pagination

I have jsp page which diplays a huge data in table format in the jsp ..I want to add pagination so that by default only 20 entries are displayed in the page and click next to get other details..Please do send me the best links for pagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use some param to maintain current slot of data for example pageNo=1 , Should fetch 1-20, pageNo=2 should fetch 20-40. and fetch only data when required.
- There are many such view available. one of this is [displayTag.](http://displaytag.sf.net/)
- Also there is [pageSorter jQuery plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html)